# Basemap drawparallels tick label color

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow, matplotlib-basemap

I have possibly a simple question. A simplified version of my code is below:

```
# get rid of white stripe on map
ionst, lons=addcyclic(ionst, lons)

#Setting figure attributes
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,15),frameon=False, facecolor='gray')

#map settings
m=Basemap(llcrnrlon=-180, llcrnrlat=-87.5, urcrnrlon=180, urcrnrlat=87.5,rsphere=6467997, resolution='l', projection='cyl',area_thresh=10000, lat_0=0, lon_0=0)

#Creating 2d array of latitude and longitude
lon, lat=np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
xi, yi=m(lon, lat)

#plotting data onto basemap
cs=m.imshow(varcor, interpolation=None, alpha=.8, cmap='seismic', vmin=-.02, vmax=.02)
vert=plt.axvline(x=-75, color='black', linewidth=5)

#drawing grid lines
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,90.,30.),labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=20)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,45.), labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=20)

#drawing coast lines
m.drawcoastlines()
```

When I call the drawparallels and drawmeridians argument, the labels are set according to the array I specify. I figured out how to change the size of tick labels but I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the color. I tried feeding in directly an argument color=, I tried tick_params, I tried xticks, yticks, etc...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After extensive searching I finally found a solution on the web. Not straight forward but it works:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def setcolor(x, color):
     for m in x:
         for t in x[m][1]:
             t.set_color(color)
m = Basemap(lon_0=0)
m.drawcoastlines()
par = m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30),labels=[1,0,0,1])
setcolor(par,'r')
merid = m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,360,60),labels=[1,0,0,1])
setcolor(merid,'r')
plt.show()
```

from https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/145